# TUGMOs2012 grade9 equation

Tags: contest-math, roots, sums-of-squares

> Find all solutions $x\in\Bbb R$ of the equation 
>   $$\sqrt{7x^2​-22x+28}​+\sqrt{7x^2​+8x+13}​+\sqrt{31x^2​+14x+4}​=5x+10.$$

My attempt:
i substitute $$a=\sqrt{7x^2​-22x+28} , \quad b=\sqrt{7x^2​+8x+13} ,​ \quad c=\sqrt{31x^2​+14x+4}​$$ then

$$a+b+c=5x+10, \quad a^2+b^2​+c^2​=-45x^2​+5x-35.$$

But I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Could you clarify how you got from 
$$
a+b+c=5x+10
$$
to 
$$
a^2+b^2​+c^2​=-45x^2​+5x-35$$ ?

Comment: i substitute $a=\sqrt{7x^2​-22x+28}, b=..., c=... $ from above

Comment: Are you sure the question is typed correctly? Graphing it gives no real solutions.

Comment: thanks i think this do not have real solution.

Comment: @CellWall, I have solved your question. Edit your question and detail your attempt (show a real attempt and write at least 3-4 lines like who is $a,b,...$ a.s.o.) and I will post my solution.

Comment: There are two complex roots.